# View logic in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Spring MVC application with JPA

I have flow of my application like:

```
@Controller
Class
```

---> returning a view (JSP) page.

Before returning to view I would like to modify contents or before sending it to entity persistence service layer , would like some values to be altered.Where shall I introduce those classes?

EDIT :

I am clear about rendering the data from database and displaying to front view.
What I actually want to ask is like :

```
A a = aService.findXXX(aId);
//here i want some operations to be performed for specific view while converting it to dto and sending it to UI.
```

Where the class for doing the same would be introduced else my controller will have very large line of code sp. to what has to be displayed to sp. view?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want (a specific example would be helpful), but you may be looking for interceptors.

Comment: @chrylis pl chk now..

Answer (score 1):

As @chrylis said, it's not very clear what you are asking. But if I understood you correctly, this will help you.

The usual pattern is that your `@Controller` has a `@Autowired` service reference

```
@Autowired
private MyService myService;
```

and that `@Service` has a `@Autowired` reference to DAO class (annotated with `@Repository`). Service encapsulates business logic, and DAO layer is responsible for interaction with database.

In your case, you would call some service method from controller, service would alter the entity and pass it down to DAO, and controller then fills the necessary data to `Model` which is used for rendering appropriate view.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand, but if it's just a matter of converting a domain object to UI friendly form then you can just put that code in some utility class, to keep controller code relaxed from conversion logic.